# Loop through h3 elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementsbytagname

everybody. I wanna make a `for` loop outputting my `h3` elements.  I could do it for one of them but to have them all, it doesn't output the content.
And the `a` in the loop is for making inner links of my `h3` in a long page.

```js
function showH() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("H3");

  let str = '<a href="">';
  for (var i =0; i < x.length; i++) {
    str += x[i] + "</a>";
  }
  document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<p id="get"></p>
<button onclick="showH()">click</button>
```

**this code outputs:**

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement][object HTMLHeadingElement]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is an array of HTMLHeadingElements. To get the text, use `.innerText`.

You also have some broken logic in your `for` loop. The first link will always work, but the links after will not be properly rendered because the start of the link tag is set to `str` and never added again.

```js
function showH() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("H3");
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    str += '<a href="">' + x[i].innerText + "</a>";
  }
  document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hello</h3>
<h3>World</h3>
<h3>!</h3>
<p id="get"></p>
<button onclick="showH()">click</button>
```